# I am having some trouble submitting an order adjustment to Amazon via the Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

The XML I am submitting for customer refund request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>A24MUCS*****</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderAdjustment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderAdjustment>
    <AmazonOrderID>105-3616276-******</AmazonOrderID>
    <AdjustedItem>
        <AdjustmentReason>CustomerCancel</AdjustmentReason>
        <ItemPriceAdjustments>
            <Component>
                <Type>Principal</Type>
                <Amount currency="USD">0.09</Amount>
            </Component>
            <Component>
                <Type>Shipping</Type>
                <Amount currency="USD">4.87</Amount>
            </Component>
        </ItemPriceAdjustments>
    </AdjustedItem>
</OrderAdjustment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

On submitting the XML the error returned by Amazon is:
   Error 5000:This is a malformed or invalid XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML does not seem malformed or invalid. However it is missing the `AmazonOrderItemCode` or `MerchantOrderItemID` which needs to be stated before `AdjustmentReason`, which is why it doesn't validate.